# Psilocybin for treatment of anxiety disorder

Tags: psychopharmacology, anxiety

Has psilocybin been used for treatment of anxiety disorder? I've mostly found it used in the treatment of depression in patients diagnosed with cancer ([Nichols et al. 2017](http://doi.org/10.1002/cpt.557)) and patients not diagnosed with anything at all ([Griffiths et al. 2006](http://doi.org/10.1007/s00213-006-0457-5)). Alternatively, how legitimate is it to generalize the results of the cancer patients to a chronic anxiety disorder patient?

Nichols, D. E., Johnson, M. W., & Nichols, C. D. (2017). [Psychedelics as medicines: an emerging new paradigm.](http://doi.org/10.1002/cpt.557) Clinical Pharmacology & Therapeutics, 101(2), 209-219.

Griffiths, R. R., Richards, W. A., McCann, U., & Jesse, R. (2006). [Psilocybin can occasion mystical-type experiences having substantial and sustained personal meaning and spiritual significance.](http://doi.org/10.1007/s00213-006-0457-5) Psychopharmacology, 187(3), 268-283.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There has been some preliminary research in the 1960's. From "The neurobiology of psychedelic drugs: implications for the treatment of mood disorders" by Vollenweider and Kometer:

> Psycholytic therapy was introduced by Ronald Sandison and applied in
> Europe at 18 treatment centres. In psycholytic therapy, low to
> moderate doses of LSD (50–100 μg), psilocybin (10–15 mg) or,
> sporadically, ketamine were used repeatedly as an adjunct in
> psychoanalytically oriented psychotherapy to accelerate the
> therapeutic process by facilitating regression and the recollection
> and release of emotionally loaded repressed memories, and by
> increasing the transference reaction. A review of 42
> studies reported impressive improvement rates in (mostly
> treatment-resistant) patients with anxiety disorders (improvement in
> 70% of patients), depression (in 62% of patients), personality
> disorders (in 53–61% of patients), sexual dysfunction (in 50% of
> patients) and obsessive–compulsive disorders (in 42% of patients).
>
> Unfortunately, the majority of these studies had serious
> methodological flaws by contemporary standards. In particular, with
> the absence of adequate control groups and follow-up measurements and
> with vague criteria for therapeutic outcome, the studies did not
> clearly establish whether it was the drug or the therapeutic
> engagement that produced the reported beneficial effect. It was also
> difficult to draw firm conclusions regarding potential long-term
> efficacy. Nevertheless, the studies provide a conceptual framework for
> the application of psychedelics, with the data suggesting that the
> most promising indication for psychedelic use might be found in the
> treatment of depression and anxiety disorders.

Comment: It's part of the new wave of treating depression (and what not) with psychedelics: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5228719/ There's a trial even for OCD: https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03300947